# $scope.item don't return items to ng-repeat in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie in AngularJs.
I'm trying to follow an example of W3CSchool but am having problems.
So here are my codes

My html

```
<head>       
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26 /angular.min.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="estabController"> 
       <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="estab in item">
           <td>{{ estab.estabNome }}</td>
           <td>{{ estab.latitude }}</td>
           <td>{{ estab.longitude }}</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
<script>
    function estabController($scope,$http){
        $http.get("http://192.168.1.6/projetos/campos/estabJson.php")
        .success(function(response){$scope.item = response;});
    }
</script>
```

My Php File

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '123456';
$dbname = 'websupor_campos';
$conn = new mysqli("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT estabNome, latitude, longitude FROM estabelecimento");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"Nome":"'  . $rs["estabNome"] . '",';
$outp .= '"Latitude":"'   . $rs["latitude"]        . '",';
$outp .= '"Longitude":"'. $rs["longitude"]     . '"}'; 
}
 $outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

In the Firebug console I can read the answer 200k OK and read the generated json , something like

> [{"Nome":"Rancho SB","Latitude":"-22.705875200595320","Longitude":"-45.576378515405280"},{"Nome":"Academia de Jud� do Jo�o","Latitude":"-22.744470000000000","Longitude":"-45.588863000000000"},{"Nome":"Academia de Balet da Vivian","Latitude":"-22.740120044832324","Longitude":"-45.588667611639380"},{"Nome":"Academia Lua Nova","Latitude":"-22.732081200000000","Longitude":"-45.563733000000010"}]

The code is the same as w3C , but locally (I use xampp in Windows 8.1)is not working. Did I miss anything ?

Thank for all
Marco Aurélio/Sao Paulo-Brazil

Answer (score 1):

The property names in your JSON are `Nome`, `Latitude`, and `Longitude`, so you need to use those:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="estab in item">
   <td>{{ estab.Nome }}</td>
   <td>{{ estab.Latitude }}</td>
   <td>{{ estab.Longitude }}</td>
 </tr>
```

I would also strongly suggest that you find a way to construct your JSON that doesn't involve tacking together little bits of strings and database values. That's bound to get you into a whole bunch of problems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your suggestion on return json . This has to do with security, right?

Comment: @MarcoAurélio Yes, it's important both for security, and also simply for the sake of not having your app break because of some unescaped values.

Answer (score 0):

your data is not accessible to the dom on load. After you assign the data to $scope.item you need to trigger the watch cycle again with `$scope.$apply()`